# Output year and month with a string

Tags: sql

Trying to output something like:

`2016,11`

Using this:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE()) + ',' + MONTH(GETDATE())) AS YearMonth
```

Am I missing something in convert? Because I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type
>   int.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` both return a number. You must convert them separately in order to use them in string concatenation.  The error is due to the `YEAR(GETDATE()) + ',' + MONTH(GETDATE())`, which is taken as *second parameter to `CONVERT` in total...

Comment: Khrys, one question: What about a month below 10? Do you expect *2016,2* or *2016,02* (see the leading zero in `02`)?

Comment: Thanks Shnungo, but the leading 0 isn't important in this case. I accepted the Sam Marion solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE())) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),  MONTH(GETDATE())) AS YearMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing converting the output of `MONTH()` to a string.  Here is one method:

```
select datename(year, getdate()) + ',' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(255)) as YearMonth
```

`datename()` is convenient because it returns a string.  Unfortunately, for month it returns the name of the month, rather than the number.

You could also do:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 120), '-', ',')
```

Or use `format()` in SQL Server 2012+:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy,MM')
```

Comment: I think you wanted to convert with 120 rather than 12... Btw: Is it sure to rely on delimiter characters (like the hyphen in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `CONVERT` with 112 to reach a **string** without delimiters ("20161110"). Converting this to `VARCHAR(*6*)` will implicitly cut the day. One (in most cases positiv) side-effect: You will get a low month zero padded (e.g. *2016,04*). Then I use `STUFF` to insert the `,`:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112),5,0,',')
```

If you do not like the zero padded month, you could replace the `0` in `STUFF` like this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME={d'2016-04-05'};
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@d,112),5,CASE WHEN MONTH(@d)<10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,',')
```